# Custom Data Types containing multiple standard types in Umbraco v6

Tags: c#, types, umbraco

[EDIT: Added answer]

Does anyone know of a way to create a custom type in Umbraco that can contain an ultimate picker along with other types? I have already tried the suggested packages in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061089/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-umbraco-custom-data-type-that-basically-was-a-grouping-o) but none of them allow use of the UP. I have followed the tutorials to make char limiter which gives me the basics but this has me stumped.

Comment: What and where is RepeatableCustomContent.config? Also, if you have an answer that works, please add it as an answer.

Comment: @Digbyswift done mate. Sorry I was in a rush at work.

Answer (score 0):

While rooting through the source for the [Repeatable Custom Content Package](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/repeatable-custom-content)(which I found through the question I linked to in my question above) I stumbled upon an extremely simple solution. Add the Ultimate Picker to "RepeatableCustomContent.config" Simple but I couldn't find any clue through google. Anyway hope this can help someone else.